# How to show quote_id in response of /carts/mine/totals API in magento-2.1?

Tags: magento-2.1, api, rest-api, order-totals

I want to show `quote_id` in response of `/carts/mine/totals` API in **magento-2.1.** Anybody guide me.

Comment: anybody help me.

Comment: this api already requires quote_id in request so why you need it again in response

Comment: we need it in totals api response.